# problem transfering intr characters from one servlet to another

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

I have one input field which the user can write whatever then want including international lang characters.

The first servlet has;

```
 protected void doWork(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"), true);
out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>");
...
out.println("<input type=text name=someText  style='width:10em;'>");
```

The servlet proceeds with a submit button to a second servlet having the following key lines;

```
 if(httpRequest.getCharacterEncoding() == null)
            httpRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String someText= httpRequest.getParameter("someText");
```

i get something weird like: ÅÅÄ°iÃÃ¼ÃÃ¶ÃÃ§IÄ± when i proceed with debug.

What am i doing wrong?

thanks for the help,

Comment: Your `PrintWriter` approach is clumsy. Just do `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` *before* getting `response.getWriter()`. No need to wrap in `InputStreamReader`. Plus, emitting HTML in a servlet is a very poor practice. It should be done in a JSP. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info and http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html.

Answer (score 1):

Set character coding to UTF directly with

```
httpRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

No need to check null, it will never be null. Container/Appserver sets it with default ISO-8859-1.
This should solve your problem.

Comment: you are right it never set utf-8 properly but also i had to move that code line up to doWork in the second servlet.

i used to set encoding and do similar stuff with utf-8 inside the method. Setting whatever i needed to set before doing anything solved my problem. 


Thanks everyone.

btw MTilsted thanks for your suggestion but the servlet didnt buy it:)

Comment: i will post exactly what i mean 5 hours later, apparently i cannot answer my own post because im not logged in

Answer (score -1):

You may need to add accept-charset='UTF-8' to your form: 
(Something like:

```
<form accept-charset='UTF-8' ... >
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: You should only use accept-charset='utf-8' if you send the page as uft-8. Don't try to use it to change encoding of the form to something different from the page. (This is needed with some browsers, due to a fuckup in the html standard, where they newer specified encoding used to submit forms.).

And on an unrelated note: Please don't use out.println to produce html output from a servlet. It will be impossible to maintain when you mix code and html. Use a tool such as Velocity to seperate your html and java.

http://velocity.apache.org - you should be able to get it up and running in under an hour).

Comment: Doesn't work in normal browser. It works in MSIE only and even then, it has a dangerous bug with it. Don't ever use `<form accept-charset>`.

Comment: But only buggy versions of MSIE need it. All the other browsers know that they should just send the reply with the same encoding as the page. So let me add: ONLY USE THAT ACCEPT-CHARSET if you serve the page as UTF-8. Newer use it to try to change encoding to something different from your page.

Comment: And some versions of Firefox need it too. It should be safe to use as specified in my "IMPORTANT NOTE" section.